# Deleting a SharePoint Infopath column leads to Workflow status page giving error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, infopath

I deleted a column in my InfoPath sharepoint list form, and now when I try and visit the "Workflows" status page from any list item it throws an exception. the logs show this:

> System.ArgumentException: Column 'TriageWo' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Lists/Project Initiation    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.GetFieldByInternalName(String strName, Boolean bThrowException)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.GetIStatusAsText(Int32 iStatus)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.GetIStatusAsHtml(Int32 iStatus)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.GetIStatusAsHtml()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPage.StrStatus(SPWorkflow wf)     at ASP._layouts_workflow_aspx._*Render*_control11(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(H...

How do I recover??

edit:

I tried just creating a new "TriageWo" column but get this error now:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.GetIStatusAsText(Int32 iStatus)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.GetIStatusAsHtml(Int32 iStatus)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflow.GetIStatusAsHtml()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WorkflowPage.StrStatus(SPWorkflow wf)     at ASP._layouts_workflow_aspx._*Render*_control11(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Cont...

Comment: What if it can't find a field because you deleted it, ON PURPOSE? I have run into this problem for a valid case of deleting a column in a list.  Now I cannot access the Workflows status page for that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I killed all running workflows on the list, and was able to see the Workflow Status pages again.